# Where does Android interpret the media button?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Where does Android convert the physical media button (in the headset cable) into logical actions (like NEXT, STOP, SPEECH QUERY)?

Is there a way of changing this assignment (ie creating other actions out of it)?

NB: I tried to install a MediaButtonReceiver. But it only sees the interpreted key. So I only see the keypress, after the key has been released earlier enough not to trigger a SPEECH QUERY.

Update: I see the raw key events, that I need, in onDispatchKeyEvent as long as my app is in foreground. But how do get them when the lock screen is active?

The MediaButtonReceiver gets called when the app is in background (but only after the key has been released).

Answer (score 1):

Before your app starts playing any audio, it should hold the audio focus for the stream it will be using. This is done with a call to requestAudioFocus() which returns AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED if your request is successful.

You must specify which stream you're using and whether you expect to require transient or permanent audio focus.

```
// Request audio focus for playback
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                         // Use the music stream.
                         AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                         // Request permanent focus.
                         AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);

if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
// Start playback.
}
```

Check for more [information](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html).

To use Real Time event in your APP, the RTP is the way to go. It provides APIs for RTP (Real-time Transport Protocol), [allowing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html) applications to manage on-demand or interactive data streaming.

Comment: The problem stays the same. I only see short keypresses, which are sent to me when the button has already been released (together with the key release). They contain timestamps, but I need the events in realtime.

Comment: I can't see how the RTP APIs are giving new access to the media button. Do you have an example?